How to reset stats in "pg_stats_subscription_stats"?
I have some errors produced while making changes to some logically replicated tables. Now I want to reset the errors logged in the pg_stat_subscription_stats table in the apply_error_count column, but I can't find anything anywhere telling me how to do it.
I've tried:

SELECT pg_stat_statements_reset()
SELECT pg_stat_reset()

But these didn't reset this field ...
How do I reset this field?
For reference, the below is combining pg_stats_subscriptions and pg_stat_subscription_stats and shows the apply_error_count values:


I stumbled across this question eventually. Please remember to also tag [postgresql] when tagging a specific version like [postgresql-15]. Must regulars only follow the main tag.

There is a dedicated function for that: pg_stat_reset_subscription_stats()
The manual:

pg_stat_reset_subscription_stats ( oid ) → void
Resets statistics for a single subscription shown in the
pg_stat_subscription_stats view to zero. If the argument is NULL,
reset statistics for all subscriptions.
This function is restricted to superusers by default, but other users
can be granted EXECUTE to run the function.

So, to reset all subscriptions, run as superuser:
SELECT pg_stat_reset_subscription_stats(null);

Or pass the OID (as seen in the column pg_stat_subscription_stats.subid) to only reset that subscription.
